# Cannot open saved workspace in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have created a workspace with five folders in it. It works fine whenever I first create it. I go `File > Save Workspace as` and save it in my Documents directory. Then I close and reopen VSCode and go to open the workspace, and it isn't there. I go to open recent workspaces, and there are no files visible in explorer window. I can open the workspace configuration file but I cannot open the workspace itself.

I'm on Linux Mint tessa

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The workspace was saved without a file extension. I manually added `.code-workspace` to the filename and now I can open it as a workspace.